# Make content go down and overflow horizontal css

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure a better way to explain this except to possibly look at a site like craigslist or something.

What it does now -

```
*****
*1  *
*2  *
*3  *
*****
```

What I want -

```
*****
*147*
*258*
*369*
*****
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N8qf8/

I made a fiddle but of course I can't get the overflow to do what I want.  Any idears?  Applying overflow: auto; just gives it a scroll bar when it hits max-height, is there anything to allow to it go to the next column?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564700/putting-li-in-the-next-column-after-specific-height basically add column-count:3 to your ul css

Answer (score 1):

In supported browsers you can use [**CSS3 columns**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZHM9/)

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 70px;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
}
```

Support for this can be found [**here**](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn).

Comment: I believe Gary was right in the comments this is a duplicate question and answer, thanks for the answer though.